# Batch file to move/compress/delete files

Tags: batch-file, robocopy, winrar

I am trying to write a batch script that will run automatically daily to do the following:

1. Move files older than 2 days to from the main directory (Jason) to an archive directory.
2. Zip files in the archive directory that are older than 1 week and delete files from this directory that are older than 6 months.
3. I want to run this script from a different directory (not the directory that has the files).

I wrote the following script but it’s not working correctly.

```
REM move files older than 2 days to an archive directory
robocopy D:\Agentrics\integration\incoming\Jason D:\Agentrics\integration\incoming\Jason\archive /MOV /MINAGE:2
```

Questions:

1. How can I change the command below to zip files older than 1 week?
2. Is it possible that the zipped files can have the same creation date and time as the original files?

```
REM zip all files in the backup directory
FOR %%A IN (*.TXT*, *.cpi*) DO "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a -r "%%~nA.zip" "%%A"
FOR %%A IN (*.TXT,  *.cpi)  DO DEL "D:\Agentrics\integration\incoming\Jason\archive\.cpi*" "%%A"

REM Delete all files in the backup directory that are older than 6 months
forfiles /p D:\Agentrics\integration\incoming\Jason\archive /s /m *.* /d -500 /c "cmd /c del /q @path"
```

Comment: doesn't this work: forefiles /M *.txt /D -7 /C WinRAR a -r aa.zip @file     ?

Comment: Yes that works and thank you. Can you tell me how can i change the following script so that it only compresses files that are older than 7 days.                                                     FOR %%A IN (D:\Agentrics\integration\incoming\Mansoor\backup\*.txt*, D:\Agentrics\integration\incoming\Mansoor\backup\*.cpi*) DO "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a -r D:\Agentrics\integration\incoming\Mansoor\backup\"%%~nA.zip" "%%A"
Regards,
Mansoor

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would not use for cycle for this. I would prefer the way proposed by @harper
But still, here is the way you wanted it:

```
REM move files older than 2 days to an archive directory
forfiles /P D:\Agentrics\integration\incoming\Jason /M *.txt /S /D -2 /C "cmd /c move @file D:\Agentrics\integration\incoming\Jason\archive"
forfiles /P D:\Agentrics\integration\incoming\Jason /M *.cpi /S /D -2 /C "cmd /c move @file D:\Agentrics\integration\incoming\Jason\archive"
REM zip all files in the backup directory
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('forfiles /p D:\Agentrics\integration\incoming\Jason\archive /s /d -7') do "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a -r "%%~nA.zip" "%%a"
REM Delete all files in the backup directory that are older than 6 months
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('forfiles /p D:\Agentrics\integration\incoming\Jason\archive /s /d -183') do del D:\Agentrics\integration\incoming\Jason\archive\%%a /y
```